# pass value from java to jsp or servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

i am working on a project. my work is retrieve data from database and displaying them. if required sent to next page for further processing. my problem is i got value from database and i want to send it another jsp or servlet using href. 
          value i am retrieving is :

```
        <%=special.getString("id")%>
```

send it to:

```
      <a href="new.jsp?id=<%=special.getString("id")%>" class="action_button">Buy Now</a>
```

but when send data like this error is

[image: error message is]

is that correct? how do i do it? what is the correct method. i am struck here for long time please help me.

Comment: To which value is `special.getString("id")` evaluated?

Comment: take special.getString("id") to a variable and see if a value is assigned.I can send you a code that worked for me but a button click event not a href

Comment: i checked it and value is assigned. it will be help full if you send me the link or code.

Comment: onclick="document.location='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/myServelet?prop-id=<%=prop.getID() %>'"

Comment: the error. Unknown property "contextPath".  i am using netbeans 7.2 btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're serious about JSP development ditch scriptlets (which went out of common use 10+ years ago) and familiarize yourself with the Java Standard Tag Libraries and JSP Expression Language.

I am not quite sure what 'special' is here, however using EL your code will look something like the below:

```
<!-- special is an object with a method getId()-->
<a href="new.jsp?id=${special.id}" class="action_button">Buy Now</a>
```

or

```
<!-- special is an object with a method getString(String key) -->
<a href="new.jsp?id=${special.getString('id')}" class="action_button">Buy Now</a>
```

If this doesn't work then there is no bean with key 'special' in any scope.

Note that if you are working with a database in your JSP you should consider refactoring to use the standard JSTL SQL tags. See below for an example:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_sql_query_tag.htm

See also:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.htm

http://beginnersbook.com/2013/11/jsp-expression-language-el/

*Note for the second example to work your app need to be compliant with the Servlet 3 specification (as passing mthod params was nut supported in EL before this). See further: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6337222/1356423

Comment: special is  ResultSet. sorry if my question is not clear. which are retrieved from database and i m displaying then like this                           <%   While(special.next()){    %>
           <ul class="features">
                        <li><%= special.getString("company")%></li>
                        <li><%= special.getString("catagory")%></li>
                     </ul>
                    <div class="footer">
                      <a href="new.jsp">more details</a>
                    </div>
               <%     }        %>

Comment: when i click on 'more details' it should go to new.jsp where it can display more detials about that particular company. for that i need to send 'id' of that particular row to see more details of that particular row. how do i sent id of that particular row to new jsp where i can retrieve full details and display it in new.jsp page?? or am i doing it wrong? my main problem is when i click on 'more details' all details of that row should go to next page i.e. new.jsp. how do i do it???

Comment: As I said previously scriptlets are hideous, ancient technology you should not be using, see here for db example with JSTL and EL. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_sql_query_tag.htm

Comment: thanks for the help. i know i am using wrong code. i just want solution. thanks you very much

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes around `id` instead double.

```
"new.jsp?id=<%=special.getString('id')%>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use single quote inside double quote. 
I am trying to type code but not able to type.
now it should work

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your quotes first or use single quotes so that your double quotes can work:

*Note:* Untested.

```
<a href='new.jsp?id=<%=special.getString("id")%>' class="action_button">Buy Now</a>
```

Comment: tried that.. for your reference it does not work. href should be in " "

Comment: Not really, it's still a recognizable HTML standard.

Comment: does `<%= special.getString("id")%>` return any value at all?

Answer (score 0):

I see in your error message it says `DOUBLE_WHITESPACE in QUERY`. I would suggest you try [encoding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) you url.

```
  <% String id=java.net.URLEncoder.encode(special.getString("id") , "UTF-8");%>
  <a href='new.jsp?id=<%=id%>' class="action_button">Buy Now</a>
```